# Livewire Pagination removes URL Part

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

I have this component to render paginated results:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire\Accounts;

use App\Models\Account;
use Livewire\Component;
use Livewire\WithPagination;

class Index extends Component
{
    use WithPagination;
    public $search;
    public $accounts;

    public function render()
    {
        if ($this->search) {
            $this->resetPage();
            $this->accounts = Account::search($this->search)
                ->orWhere('fullname', 'LIKE', '%'.$this->search.'%')
                ->orWhere('email', 'LIKE', '%'.$this->search.'%')->orderBy('fullname')->paginate(12);
        } else {
            $this->accounts = Account::orderBy('fullname')->paginate(12);
        }

        return view('livewire.accounts.index', ['accounts' => $this->accounts]);
    }
}
```

Within the Blade Template I have `{{ $accounts->links('pagination.tailwind') }}`
The Pagination View is a copy of vendor/livewire/tailwind.blade.php

The URL is htttp://mydomain.com/accounts.

When I click a pagination link, the URL becomes htttp://mydomain.com/?page=2 instead of htttp://mydomain.com/accounts/?page=2

Comment: Have you altered the pagination blade view in any way?

Comment: Only changed some CSS classes, but the same issue occures with `{{ $accounts->links() }}` using default view

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but just for now I suggest adding `use WithPagination` in your parent component too and It's working.
The problem is I don't think its a good way
[You can follow the issue in GitHub with @calebporzio](https://github.com/livewire/livewire/issues/1816)

I hope it helps